# Display current value of option in tmux display-message

Tags: linux, configuration, configuration-files, tmux

I am binding a key in my tmux configuration for `synchronize-panes` window option. I would also like to display the current state of the same option with the same key press. So far, I have tried:

```
# one or more of the following
bind-key S run-shell "tmux setw synchronize-panes; TMUX_STATUS=`tmux showw synchronize-panes`;tmux display-message $TMUX_STATUS"
bind-key S "setw synchronize-panes; display-message `showw synchronize-panes`"
bind-key S run-shell "tmux setw synchronize-panes; TMUX_STATUS=$(tmux showw synchronize-panes); tmux display-message $TMUX_STATUS"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve that with the following binding in .tmux.conf

Tested with tmux 2.4

```
# Toggle synchronize-panes with ^S m
bind S \
    set synchronize-panes \;\
    display "Sync #{?synchronize-panes,ON,OFF}"
```

You have details about tmux variables and format in the man page.
https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-tmux/

Comment: The man page is 104k. The problem is finding the answer in under 2 days.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky true words. I had to wait ~40 days though ;)